# Finding the LVM root volume while in the Grub 0.95 CLI without access to the grub.conf file

Tags: linux, redhat, lvm, rhel5, grub

If I have my root device is a LVM logical volume, how can I figure out the path via the Grub CLI without access to the original `grub.conf` file?

This is for use in the `kernel` command's `root` and `rd_LVM_LV` parameters. E.g.:

```
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.34.8-68.fc13.i686.PAE ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_sever1-root rd_LVM_LV=vg_server1/root
```

Normally, you could tab in the CLI to get hints as far as file location, available HDs, etc.. However, I am not sure how to obtain the volume group's name or the root logical volume.

Comment: If it is an option, boot from a decent Live CD like [grml](http://grml.org) to find out details about the LVM configuration. Then adjust the Grub configuration on the fly or maybe fix it from within the Live CD.

Comment: Thanks daff. Was hoping to find a solution that did not involve a Live CD. However, it could very well be the only way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grub` has a `cat` command, so you can look at `grub.conf` from the prompt:

```
grub> root (hd0,0)
 Filesystem type is ext2fs, partition type 0x83

grub> cat /grub/grub.conf
#splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splashimage.xpm.gz
timeout 30
[...]
```

This may not help if the drive you're working on no longer *has* the grub.conf file, but even if it's not bootable the file is still accessible.

Comment: I was hoping to find a solution when you *no longer* have access to the `grub.conf` file for whatever reason. Based on my research, seems that there is no way to figure out if partition is a PV for an LVM just from the grub shell. I was hoping someone could enlighten me :-)

Comment: Well, if you try to run `root (hdX,X)` within grub, it should tell you the filesystem type, which will be different for LVM than it is for standard partitions, so you can _detect_ an LVM physical volume that way. However, that doesn't help with any of the rest of the LVM layers.

Comment: Noticed that during the boot process, right before it attempts to mount the root volume, there's a printed list of the LVM LV's that were auto-detected. This might be sufficient information for a trial-and-error process. Not the preferable way to go about it but could be effective nonetheless.